# Safari 7 jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, safari

I did search the topics on SO for similar issues, but since Safari 7 just got released, it may be that similar topics don't exist or my searching skills are pretty lame. Therefore I apologise if it had been already asked and solved. 
My issue is that the following code: 
`$("input[name='UserManagement_Form_State'").replaceWith('<select id="UserManagement_Form_State" name="UserManagement_Form_State"></select>');` does nothing in Safari, the input field remains unchanged (as in it doesn't become a select). 
I was wondering if anyone else ran into something similar (maybe with previous versions of Safari) and if there is a fix. jQuery is loaded and it runs (console.logging works before the chunk, after the chunk, other things work and so on).

Many thanks!

Comment: you are missing closing `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake... Replace your js by : (you didn't close `[]` in the selector)

```
$("input[name='UserManagement_Form_State']").replaceWith('<select id="UserManagement_Form_State" name="UserManagement_Form_State"></select>');
```

And prefere to use this solution :

```
$("input[name='UserManagement_Form_State']").replaceWith(
    $('<select />').attr('id','UserManagement_Form_State')
                   .attr('name','UserManagement_Form_State')
 );
```

Comment: Thank you, I am blind it seems! Really really thank you. Still 7 minutes until i can mark the answer as solution and i can't vote up as i don't have enough rep :((